# Using slanted text (slshape) with newpxtext and tgpagella like with mathpazo (Palatino font packages)

Tags: italic, mathpazo, slanted

When I use the `mathpazo` package (Palatino font), the font shapes generated by using the `\textit` and `\textsl` commands (or alternatively the `\itshape` and `\slshape` commands) look different as intended: The first one produces italic text, the second one produces slanted text.

However, when I use the `newpxtext` or the `tgpagella` package (also Palatino font), both `\textit` and `\textsl` produce **italic text only**. You may try this out with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{newpxtext}
%\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}
\texttt{itshape}: \textit{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}

\texttt{slshape}: \textsl{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}
\end{document}
```

By the way: I use MikTeX and pdflatex.

When running this example with `tgpagella`, a warning shows up, saying that `sl` is not available and `it` is used instead:

*LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'OT1/qpl/m/sl' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape 'OT1/qpl/m/it' tried instead on input line 10.* (taken from the .log file)

However, no warning appears when I use `newpxtext`. Apparently, `sl` is just defined to be the same font shape as `it` for this package.

**My question:** Is there a way to use the `newpxtext` package *and* be able to use actually slanted text? I am particularly interested in using `newpxtext` instead of the other two packages since I want to use it jointly with the `newpxmath` package as recommended in many forums.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Slanted text fonts are fairly rare, especially for serif fonts.  I am not sure, but seriously doubt that either Palatino (or pagella) provides such a shape.  Italic is the usual substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I redefine `\textsl` and `\slshape` to invoke the `mathpazo` font.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\let\svtextsl\textsl
\renewcommand\textsl[1]{\bgroup\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\svtextsl{#1}\egroup}
\let\svslshape\slshape
\renewcommand\slshape{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\svslshape}

\begin{document}
\texttt{itshape}: \textit{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}

\texttt{slshape}: \textsl{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}

Normal text and \slshape now in slshape. \upshape Back ``up'' again.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The only *pitfall*, if you want to call it that, is that if you are operating in this revised `\slshape` and change the font family, as in `\rmfamily`, you will return to the italic shape, because (as the OP knows) the `slshape` is unknown to the default font family, be it `nepxtext` or `tgpagella`.

Comment: To clarify the last sentence for a future reader: If you change the font family at some point in your document (e.g. by calling `\sffamily`), you will not be able to use this secondary font's `\slshape`. Reason: You will jump back to using Palatino since it is now "hard-coded" within the re-definition of the `\slshape`/`\textsl` command. As a solution, you can define different `\slshape` commands for different font families (but this might not be the most elegant way to do it).

Comment: @TopQuark Correct, though I would think for most situations, this would not naturally occur at the user level (invoking a different font family in the midst of `\slshape`).  However, some macros are known to invoke a font family which could, in these situations, lead to unanticipated results.

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute the font call for `\slshape`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{zpl\zpl@figurealign\zpl@figurestyle}{m}{sl}{<-> pplro8t}{}%
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{zpl\zpl@figurealign\zpl@figurestyle}{b}{sl}{<-> pplbo8t}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{upshape}: \textup{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}

\texttt{itshape}: \textit{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}

\texttt{slshape}: \textsl{The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that this will not follow possible choices about oldstyle figures you make when loading `newpxtext`.

I'd avoid it. I generally agree with Knuth's typographical choices, but definitely not about slanted type that I find essentially indistinguishable from upright type and ugly.